# How to call a function that prints multiple arrays in JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to get the allArrays variable to include the already defined arrays, and then print them all in a console.log using the function. When I try this i get 3 arrays with undefined values, why is that and how would this work ?

```
var allArrays = [food, drinks, random];
var food = ["burger","fries","milkshake","sushi"];
var drinks= ["cola","soda","pop"];
var random = ["suck","give","fix me","wooww"];

function selectallArrays (allArrays){
    for (var i =0; i<allArrays.length; i++) {
        console.log(allArrays);
        }
    console.log("--------");
    }

    selectallArrays(allArrays);
```

Comment: because the `food`, `drinks`, and `random` arrays are not defined when you create `allArrays`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should work now.

```
var food = ["burger","fries","milkshake","sushi"];
var drinks= ["cola","soda","pop"];
var random = ["suck","give","fix me","wooww"];
var allArrays = [food, drinks, random];
function selectallArrays (allArrays){
    for (var i =0; i<allArrays.length; i++) {
        console.log(allArrays);
        }
    console.log("--------");
    }

    selectallArrays(allArrays);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the order of declaring & initializing the array, otherwise it will log `undefined`.

All the arrays are declared with var statement and they wont be hoisted.
When `var allArrays = [food, drinks, random];` is executed `food`,`drinks` & `random` array was not initialized.

```
var food = ["burger","fries","milkshake","sushi"];
var drinks= ["cola","soda","pop"];
var random = ["suck","give","fix me","wooww"];
var allArrays = [food, drinks, random];
```

Comment: probably doesn't need an answer tbh